# Testing fails with "Booting the kernel before calling "...\WebTestCase::createClient()" is not supported

Tags: php, symfony, testing

Somewhere between Symfony 5.0.5 and 5.0.8 the exception

> LogicException: Booting the kernel before calling
>   "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase::createClient()" is
>   not supported, the kernel should only be booted once.

is generated.  In 5.05 the test shown below passes. After updating to 5.08 the test fails. While the exception appears [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59389497/symfony-5-api-testing-createclient-logicalexception) in SO the answer does solve the present issue. What is missing in order to allow 5.08 to pass this and similar tests?

```
namespace App\Tests\Controller;

use Liip\TestFixturesBundle\Test\FixturesTrait;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class AdminControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    use FixturesTrait;

    public function setup(): void
    {
        $this->fixtures = $this->loadFixtures([
                    'App\DataFixtures\Test\OptionsFixture',
                    'App\DataFixtures\Test\NonprofitFixture',
                    'App\DataFixtures\Test\UserFixture',
                ])
                ->getReferenceRepository();
        $this->client = static::createClient();  // <-- this line causes failure
        $this->client->followRedirects();
        $this->client->request('GET', '/login');
        $this->client->submitForm('Sign in', [
            'email' => 'admin@bogus.info',
            'password' => '123Abc',
        ]);
    }

    public function testLogin()
    {
        $this->client->request('GET', '/admin/dashboard');

        $this->assertEquals(200, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the line `$this->client = static::createClient();`

before the following block:

```
$this->fixtures = $this->loadFixtures([
        'App\DataFixtures\Test\OptionsFixture',
        'App\DataFixtures\Test\NonprofitFixture',
        'App\DataFixtures\Test\UserFixture',
    ])
    ->getReferenceRepository();
```

The load fixtures is booting the kernel if it's not already booted. If you boot it first then it won't do it.

It probably shouldn't have worked in Symfony 5.05 and not sure why it was passing.

Comment: Thanks. Moving the block allowed tests that do not require any of the fixtures to pass. Unfortunately, other tests within the test class fail as it appears the fixtures are not loaded.

Comment: Reading the Liip documentation again I get the impression that the client & fixtures code should be in each test rather than in `setup()`.

Comment: Answer is accepted as it resolved the question as presented. There remains other problems created by the answer though, but that's a different issue.

Comment: The setup() should be called before every test so I doubt that would be the issue.

Comment: Maybe overwrite the tear down method so the fixtures are not removed, run one of the tests and see if the database is populated.

Comment: I've got it sorted. A number of errors on my part trying to be too clever. It's all good now.